# Can't seem to get simple Bazel python script to run

Tags: bazel

I have just switched to bazel and I am trying to figure out how to get things working. I have added the following to my bazel BUILD file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

py_binary(
    name = "Test",
    srcs = [ "Test.py" ],
    deps = [
         "@numpy",
    ],
)
```

How on earth do i get Bazel to import numpy?

When I run it, it says `no such package '@numpy//'`
And of course if i dont have any deps it says no module named numpy.
What is the syntax to be used here?

Answer (score 2):

`@numpy` is a not valid bazel [label](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.1.0/build-ref.html#labels). To use dependencies from PyPI repositories you need to use external python rules: [bazelbuild/rules_python](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/tree/master/examples/pip_install)

Comment: I tried to execute the example in `pip_install` via
`bazel run //main` but i get the error
`Skipping '//main': no such package 'main': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories.`

Comment: Running it from the main repo itself fails too:
`Skipping '//examples/pip_install:main': no such package 'examples/pip_install': Package is considered deleted due to --deleted_packages`

Comment: Wait, am i suppose to clone this into my repo or something i am really confused

Comment: You should use that example from the inner directory. And it should be `//:main`, because `main` is a target. Please read https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.1.0/build-ref.html#labels , because it is hard to work with bazel without basic knowledge